# run a function when NSWindowController appear

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I am currently searching a function like `viewDidAppear()` in `NSWindowController`. For my App, I need to display a `NSWindowController` a few times, and dismiss them with `NSApp.hide(nil)`. But when I show the Window another time, I need to clear a few fields.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Since when has NSWindowController become NSViewController?

Comment: This depends on whether you are using storyboard or XIB.

Comment: @El Tomato: sorry I'm new to Cocoa Apps. I've only had experience with iOS apps so far.

Comment: @vadian: I'm using XIB.

Comment: How do you show the window? Can you call a method of your `NSWindowController` subclass at that time?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is probably just to use an `NSViewController` to manage the window's content view (should happen automatically anyway if you're using a storyboard), and then override its `viewDidAppear()` method. But if you can't do that for some reason, you could always override `windowDidLoad()` and register for whichever `NSWindow` notifications are relevant to what you're doing (depending on what that is, `didBecomeKeyNotification` or `didChangeScreenNotification` may be helpful).